# cannot compile C program with GCC on Mac and -masm=intel

Tags: macos, gcc, x86

I'm trying to compile a C program that has some inline assembly code in Intel format. I'm using GCC 4.9 (installed via Homebrew) on Mac 10.9, and the compiler flags:

```
gcc-4.9 -m32 -masm=intel -std=gnu99 get_rating.c
```

Unfortunately I get an error:

```
error: -masm=intel not supported in this configuration
```

I've tried many different combinations of the flags, but I keep getting that error. I can't leave out the `-masm=intel` flag, because the code I'm trying to compile uses Intel.

How can I compile the program? Is it at all possible on my Mac (version 10.9) or do I need to run a virtual machine?

Answer (score 3):

The GCC [docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.2/gcc/i386-and-x86-64-Options.html#i386-and-x86-64-Options) state that Darwin does not support `intel`, so it seems you are out of luck with the direct approach. Virtual machine as you suggested, cross compiling, converting the assembler to `att`, and replacing the assembler with C are among your options - which is best for you you'll have to figure out.

HTH